# Append to a variable in awk

Tags: awk

When using `bash` I can append to a variable with `+=`.  I want to
do something similar in `awk`.  What can I use ?

```
  rl="?(+)*([$dgt])?([.,])+([$dgt])"
  rl+="?([eE]?([-+])+([$dgt]))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String variables in awk are concatenated simply by writing them side-by-side. So:

```
rl="?(+)*([$dgt])?([.,])+([$dgt])"
rl = rl "?([eE]?([-+])+([$dgt]))"
```

(the intervening whitespace is optional).

See [String Concatenation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-string-2).

---

BTW if you are trying to pass a shell variable `$dgt` into your awk program, don't do it like that - use something like `-v dgt="$dgt"` on the command line and then `rl = sprintf("?(+)*([%s])?([.,])+([%s])", dgt, dgt)` to write it into the string. You could even consider using `sprintf` to do the concatenation:

```
rl = sprintf("?(+)*([%s])?([.,])+([%s])", dgt, dgt)
rl = sprintf("%s?([eE]?([-+])+([%s]))", rl, dgt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what means your regex attempts, anyway try this:

```
$ awk '{var="foo"$1;print var}' <<< bar
foobar
```